# type casting or array indexing bug in HLSL (Unreal Engine 4)

Tags: android, hlsl, unreal-engine4

I have the following piece of code in my HLSL shader which works on Windows x64 but fails to run when deployed to Android using UE4:

```
// calcScale() returns a value between 0.0f and 7.0f, inclusive
float Scale = calcScale();

const float3 Values[] =
{
    { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f },
    { 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f },
    { 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f },
    { 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f },
    { 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f },
    { 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f },
    { 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f },
    { 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f },
    { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f }
};

int index = int(Scale);
OutDeviceColor = lerp(Values[index], Values[index + 1], Scale);
```

If I replace the last line with literals, it works:

```
OutDeviceColor = lerp(Values[0], Values[1], Scale); //works
```

I have even tried setting:

```
int index = 0; // does not help
```

I do not get any error messages in UE4Log. I tried having a cursory look at logcat too but didn't find anything suspicious. My output is a screen with the lower left portion of the screen black and green, yellow and red interpolated in the upper right portion for the screen which is what I'm guessing is an indication of a shader failing at runtime.

Comment: Afaik you can use your float variable `Scale` directly for accessing the array, without converting it to an int. Did you tried this? I looked through the HLSL documentation, but unfortunately didn't found a reference. But I'm pretty sure, that under the former DX9 HLSL reference, such an option have been described.

Comment: I think that would be highly compiler dependent if it worked. To be safe, it would be preferable to cast it to an int or uint before using it as an index.

Answer (score 0):

Hi your code is confusing: lets say scale gives you 6.5, then your int would be 6.

PS: casting in hlsl is:

```
int index = (int) Scale;
```

So you are accessing element 6 and 7, and lerp it with 6.5? Is that really what you want?

Maybe you want to write:

```
// calcScale() returns a value between 0.0f and 8.0f, inclusive
float scale = calcScale();

const float3 Values[] =
{
    { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f },
    { 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f },
    { 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f },
    { 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f },
    { 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f },
    { 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f },
    { 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f },
    { 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f },
    { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f } // YOU HAVE 9 ELEMENTS! Shouldn't scale be between 0-8???
};

int lowIndex = (int) floor(scale);
int highIndex = (int) ceil(scale);
float factor =  frac(scale); //for 6.5 frac gives you 0.5

OutDeviceColor = lerp(Values[lowIndex], Values[highIndex], factor);

//or better all in one function
OutDeviceColor = lerp(Values[floor(scale)], Values[ceil(scale)], frac(scale));
```

One thing to say. Try to avoid using ints. HLSL can access every array or vector with floats. Graphic devices are not very good in working with ints. Maybe your compiler is optimizing that anyway, but you don't know that for sure.

Keep in mind: Everything is optimized for using floats.

Good Luck

Comment: Well the point I was trying to make is that the code fails to produce any output at all. There are some changes in the code above like the lerp actually happens for Scale - (float)index instead of Scale. I am not looking for help with the logic in this case. I am trying to understand why the compiler seems to not accept the float value at all. Again, this works perfectly on Windows.

Comment: is OutDeviceColor a float3? normal output color is float4, maybe some error here? Are you sure, your scale function is within the range? maybe negative?